# [Javascript]: Does Elements created using CreateElement method, cause memory leak, if not removed properly?

Tags: javascript

I create elements using createElement method, and append it to some parent element. Later on,  I clear the innerHTML of the parent element. Will this cause memory leak ? what happens to the element that was created ? If this is a memory leak, how to handle it?. also, if there is any callback function attached to the element, does it need to be detached ?

```
var spanelem = document.createElement('span');
spanelem.onclick = function(){
CallMe();
};
var parentdiv = document.getElementById('ParentCnt');
parentdiv.appendChild(spanelem);
.....

.....
parentdiv.innerHTML = " "; //is this memory Leak ? what happens to spanelem?
```

Comment: Why do you think `document.createElement` would do anything special? No, it works exactly the same as if you had created the element via `innerHTML` or similar and assigned it to `spanelem` via a DOM selector query.

Comment: @Bergi: thanks for your advice. The question was not about creating the element, What I really wanted to know was, when we set `innerHTML=" "`,if the elements are cleared from the memory or not. Being worked in C++ for long time, It becomes a bit difficult to digest the fact that, we dont really have to bother about clearing these objects :). Also realized a very important fact from Travis answer that, call to innerHTML, instantly causes document reflow.

Comment: The elements at least won't be referenced from the DOM any more, setting `innerHTML` removes them completely. Whether the are cleared from memory depends on what else references them (e.g. your global? `spanelem` variable).

Comment: Yes. Understood the concept. Thanks to all for helping :)

Answer (score 5):

It depends.

If you have code you give - spanElem  still exists in memory ( if `var spanelem` was in global scope, and you didn't execute `spanelem = null` ), cause there is accessible reference to object.

Otherwise if spanElem has the only reference from it's onClick handler - it will be memory leak only in IE8-. All modern browsers handle such cases and clean memory on garbage collection.

I suppose you mean not right the same code, but just principle -- in such case you can check if there are no other handlers which have link to spanElem in their lexical env, if so - you can just clear reference with adding

`spanelem = null;`

after

`parentdiv.appendChild(spanelem);`

Check [more details at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

P.S. 
if you run next code

```
var spanelem = document.createElement('span');
spanelem.onclick = function(){
CallMe();
};
var parentdiv = document.getElementById('ParentCnt');
parentdiv.appendChild(spanelem);

parentdiv.innerHTML = '';

console.log(spanelem);
```

you'll find that spanelem still exists ( it will be the same, if you'll run 
 `setTimeout(function(){ console.log(spanelem); }, 9999); // some huge delay here` ) - but the only reason is that for code below we save reference for spanelem object so gc doesn't remove object. If we won't use it - gc will remove object on it's running

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response. spanelem is in local scope(In a function), so, if I do spanelem = null; after appendChild, I need not be bothered about memory leaks , Right ?

Comment: yep. If you have modern browser, you can just leave code as is. If IE<8 - then just set variable into null

Comment: Thank you very much Vasiliy.

Comment: @vivek: If `spanelem` is in a local scope, you just need to wait for the scope to go away (e.g. when the function returns and no closure keeps a reference). You don't need to nullify it.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if there is a concern regarding garbage collection then alleviating that concern requires creating a closure for the garbage collector to target.

Once all references are removed to a variable from the Variable Environment and the Lexical Environment then the variable is eligible for collection.

This means that encapsulating the variable in its own Execution Context will provide a minimum exposure to these environments. This can be done with an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE).

```
(function(){
    var spanelem = document.createElement('span');
    spanelem.onclick = function(){
        CallMe();
    };
    var parentdiv = document.getElementById('ParentCnt');
    parentdiv.appendChild(spanelem);
})()
//CONT'D
```

...cont'd: At this point the only reference remaining is through the DOM. Using appendChild causes a document reflow, and so if anything else that causes a reflow, such as .innerHTML were to occur, that entry could be removed. Later on, using `parentdiv.innerHTML = " "` will cause the entry to be removed, and the garbage collector will *eventually*, at its own pace, get to removing the memory allocation if it needs to.

Comment: Thanks for the advice for scoping the variable using IIFE. What I understand from your explanation is that, for every element we have reference through variable and through DOM. And if we manage to remove all the references which are through variables, ie by either using locally scoped variable or by setting the variables null, then rest will be managed automatically ie when reflow occurs, Garbage collector will do its job...

Comment: @vivek - Yes, that is correct. If all references (variable and DOM) are removed then the object will be eligible for GC (which is not guaranteed to run).